# Adding custom logics to Mapster's mapping, possibly with AfterMapping?

Tags: c#, mapster

### The Question

After mapping `Input` to `Output`, the returned `Input` must have an incrementing number in its `Entries[i].Id`, (i.e. `Entries[0].Id = 1`, `Entries[1].Id = 2`, `Entries[2].Id = 3`, ...). So I tried to put it in `AfterMapping`:

```
[Mapper]
public interface IMyMapper {
    Output Map(Input userTableTemplate);
}

public class RegisterMyMapper : IRegister {
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config) {
        config.NewConfig<Input, Output>()
            .Map(output => output.OutputName, input => input.Name)
            .AfterMapping(output => {
                foreach (var pair in output.Entries.Select((value, index) => new {value = value, index = index})) {
                    pair.value.Id = pair.index + 1;
                }
            });
    }
}

public class Output {
    public string OutputName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}

public class Entry { public int Id { get; set; } }

public class Input { public string Name { get; set; } }
```

But when running `_myMapper.Map(myInput)` I'm getting a null reference exception, because the `private Action<Output> Action1` member of the generated code (`public partial class MyMapper : IIMyMapper`) is null:

```
public partial class MyMapper : IMyMapper
{
    private Action<Output> Action1;
    
    public Output Map(Input p1)
    {
        if (p1 == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Output result = new Output();
        
        result.OutputName = p1.Name;
        Action1.Invoke(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Current solution

Switched from `AfterMapping` to `AfterMappingInline`:

```
config.NewConfig<Input, Output>()
    .Map(output => output.OutputName, input => input.Name)
    .AfterMappingInline(output => output.Entries.SetIdValues())
```

And:

```
public static class MethodExtensions {
    public static void SetIdValues(this IEnumerable<Entry> entries) {
        foreach (var pair in entries.Select((value, index) => new {value = value, index = index}))
            pair.value.Id = pair.index + 1;
    }
}
```

...was hoping to find more elegant solution...